Getting error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'" on starting tcp::client boost::asio
I am writing a tcp client-server app using boost::asio in the likeness of redis db with a limited number of connections to the server at one time. This is my first experience with boost::asio, do not judge strictly.
client.h
#ifndef CLIENT_IMPL_H
#define CLIENT_IMPL_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

namespace io = boost::asio;
using tcp = io::ip::tcp;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class client : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<client> {

public:

    client(io::io_context &io_context, std::string const &addr, uint16_t port) 
    : socket_(io_context) {
        start(tcp::endpoint(
            io::ip::address::from_string(addr),
            port
        ));
    }

    void start(tcp::endpoint ep);

private:

    void on_connect(error_code const &err);

    void on_read(error_code const &err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted);
    void async_read();

    void on_write(error_code const &err);
    void async_write();

private:

    tcp::socket socket_;
    io::streambuf streambuf_;
    std::string request_;
    std::string response_;

};

#endif

cleint.cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "client_impl.h"

void client::start(tcp::endpoint ep) {
    socket_.async_connect(
        ep,
        [this](error_code err) {
            on_connect(err);
        }
    );
}

void client::on_connect(error_code const &err) {
    if (!err) {
        async_write();
    } else {
        socket_.close();
    }
}

void client::on_read(error_code const &err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted) {
    if (!err) {
        std::stringstream message(response_);
        message << std::istream(&streambuf_).rdbuf();
        streambuf_.consume(bytes_transmitted);

        std::cout << response_ << std::endl;
        response_.clear();

        async_write();
    } else {
        socket_.close();
    }
}

void client::async_read() {
    auto self = shared_from_this();
    io::async_read_until(
        socket_,
        streambuf_,
        "\n",
        [self](error_code err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted) {
            self->on_read(err, bytes_transmitted);
        }
    );
}

void client::on_write(error_code const &err) {
    if (!err) {
        async_read();
    } else {
        socket_.close();
    }
}

void client::async_write() {
    std::getline(std::cin, request_);
    request_ += "\n";
    io::async_write(
        socket_,
        io::buffer(request_),
        [this](error_code err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted) {
            on_write(err);
        }
    );
}

server.h
#ifndef SERVER_IMPL_H
#define SERVER_IMPL_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <regex>


namespace io = boost::asio;
using tcp = io::ip::tcp;
using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::placeholders;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {

public:
    session(tcp::socket socket, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> &storage) : 
        socket_(std::move(socket)),
        storage_ {storage} {}

    void start();

private:

    void async_read();
    void on_read(error_code err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted);

    void async_write();
    void on_write(error_code err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted);

    void message_handler(std::string const &message);
    void on_put(std::string const &message);
    void on_get(std::string const &message);
    void on_del(std::string const &message);
    void on_count(std::string const &message);
    void on_dump(std::string const &message);
    bool is_valid_key(std::string const &key);
    bool is_valid_txt(std::string const &fname);

    std::string get_from_storage(std::string const &key);
    void put_from_storage(std::string const &key, std::string const &value);

    tcp::socket socket_;
    io::streambuf streambuf_;
    std::string buffer_;
    std::string response_;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> &storage_;
    const static std::regex key_regex_;
    const static std::regex txt_regex_;

};

class server {

public:

    server(io::io_context& io_context, std::uint16_t port) :
        io_context_(io_context),
        acceptor_(io_context_, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
        async_accept();
    }

    void async_accept();

  private:

    io::io_context& io_context_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> storage_;

};

#endif

server.cpp
#include "server_impl.h"

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <cstddef>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

/* session implementation */

const std::regex session::key_regex_("[A-Za-z0-9]+");
const std::regex session::txt_regex_("[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.txt");

void session::start() {
    async_read();
}

void session::async_read() {
    io::async_read_until(
        socket_,
        streambuf_,
        "\n",
        std::bind(&session::on_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2)
    );
}

void session::on_read(error_code err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted) {
    if (!err) {
        std::stringstream message(buffer_);
        message << std::istream(&streambuf_).rdbuf();
        streambuf_.consume(bytes_transmitted);

        message_handler(buffer_);
        async_write();
        buffer_.clear();

        async_read();
    } else {
        socket_.close();
    }
}

void session::async_write() {
    io::async_write(
        socket_,
        io::buffer(response_),
        std::bind(&session::on_write, shared_from_this(), _1, _2)
    );
}

void session::on_write(error_code err, std::size_t bytes_transmitted) {
    if (!err) {
        async_write();
    } else {
        socket_.close();
    }
}

void session::message_handler(std::string const &message) {

    if (message.starts_with("PUT ")) {
        on_put(message);
    } else if (message.starts_with("GET ")) {
        on_get(message);
    } else if (message.starts_with("DEL ")) {
        on_del(message);
    } else if (message.starts_with("COUNT ")) {
        on_count(message);
    } else if (message.starts_with("DUMP ")) {
        on_dump(message);
    } else {
        response_ = "NE";
    }

}

void session::on_put(std::string const &message) {
    std::istringstream ss(message);
    std::string tmp;
    std::string key;
    int cnt {};

    ss >> tmp;
    while (ss >> tmp) {
        if (++cnt == 3) {
            response_ = "NE\n";
            return;
        }
        if (cnt == 1) {
            if (!is_valid_key(tmp)) {
                response_ = "NE\n";
                return;
            }
            key = tmp;
        }
    }

    if (cnt != 2) { 
        response_ = "NE\n";
        return;
    }

    if (std::string value = get_from_storage(key); value != "") {
        response_ = "OK " + value + "\n";
    }
    storage_[key] = tmp;
}

void session::on_get(std::string const &message) {
    std::istringstream ss(message);
    std::string tmp;
    std::string value;
    int cnt {};

    ss >> tmp;
    while (ss >> tmp) {
        if (++cnt == 2) {
            response_ = "NE\n";
            return;
        }
        if (!is_valid_key(tmp)) {
            response_ = "NE\n";
            return;
        }
        value = get_from_storage(tmp);
    }

    if (cnt != 1 || value == "") { 
        response_ = "NE\n";
        return;
    }

    response_ = "OK " + value + "\n";
}

void session::on_del(std::string const &message) {
    std::istringstream ss(message);
    std::string tmp;
    std::string value;
    int cnt {};

    ss >> tmp;
    while (ss >> tmp) {
        if (++cnt == 2) {
            response_ = "NE\n";
            return;
        }
        if (!is_valid_key(tmp)) {
            response_ = "NE\n";
            return;
        }
        value = get_from_storage(tmp);
    }

    if (cnt != 1 || value == "") { 
        response_ = "NE\n";
        return;
    }

    storage_.erase(tmp);
    response_ = "OK " + value + "\n";
}

void session::on_count(std::string const &message) {
    std::istringstream ss(message);
    std::string tmp;

    ss >> tmp;
    while (ss >> tmp) {
        response_ = "NE\n";
        return;
    }

    size_t cnt {storage_.size()};
    response_ = "OK " + std::to_string(cnt) + "\n";
}

void session::on_dump(std::string const &message) {
    std::istringstream ss(message);
    std::string tmp;
    int cnt {};

    ss >> tmp;
    while (ss >> tmp) {
        if (++cnt == 2) {
            response_ = "NE\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    if (cnt != 1 || !is_valid_txt(tmp)) { 
        response_ = "NE\n";
        return;
    }

    // dumping
    response_ = "OK\n";
}

bool session::is_valid_key(std::string const &key) {
    return std::regex_match(key, key_regex_);
}

bool session::is_valid_txt(std::string const &fname) {
    return std::regex_match(fname, txt_regex_);
}

std::string session::get_from_storage(std::string const &key) {
    if (auto it = storage_.find(key); it != storage_.end()) {
        return it->second;
    }
    return "";
}

void session::put_from_storage(std::string const &key, std::string const &value) {
    storage_[key] = value;
}


/* server implemetation */

void server::async_accept() {
    acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code err, tcp::socket socket) {
        if (!err) {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), storage_)->start();
        }
    });
}

And I run this like that
// for server

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) {
        std::cout << "usage: server <port> <limit_connections> [<dump_file>]" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    io::io_context io_context;
    server srv(io_context, static_cast<uint16_t>(std::stoi(argv[1])));
    srv.async_accept();
    io_context.run();
    return 0;
}

// for client

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        std::cout << "usage: client <ip> <port>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    io::io_context io_context;
    std::make_shared<client>(io_context, "127.0.0.1", std::stoi(argv[2]));
    io_context.run();

    return 0;
}

The server starts and listens, here is the netstat result:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4707/./Server

But when I try to start the server, I get this error immediately after startup:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
  what():  close: Bad file descriptor [system:9]


A debugger tells you that the exception is thrown from close():

This means that the connection failed (for some other reason) and you then die because you try to close a socket that may not be open.
Why Does Connect Fail?
You cancel it! async_connect does not capture shared_from_this(). The client destructs, cancelling any operations. Your close() is called after object destuction: that's Undefined Behavior.
Likely you already had shared_from_this, but you removed it. Why? If you didn't remove it, you would get a bad_weak_ptr exception. That's because shared_from_this cannot be used from the constructor: Why shared_from_this can't be used in constructor from technical standpoint?
Changing:

start() to be separate from construction
boost::enable_shared_from_this to std::enable_shared_from_this (because you were using std::make_shared!!)
adding the missing self captures

Now you only have the issue that std::getline blocks all IO.
Other problems
Your server has issues handling the buffer:
std::stringstream message(buffer_);
message << std::istream(&streambuf_).rdbuf();
streambuf_.consume(bytes_transmitted);

message_handler(buffer_);

Here,buffer_ does not contain the request. Perhaps you are missing buffer_ = message.str()? May I suggest improved naming so it is less confusing to read this code? I'd probably consider something like:
std::string message;
if (getline(std::istream(&streambuf_), message))
    message_handler(message);

The server also causes a write loop by calling more writes from on_write. Instead I'd move the new read to on_write to avoid handling overlapping requests (because you donot support it, because e.g. response_ is shared).
DEMO
With some other minor fixes, and just "living" with stuff like the required space after "COUNT ":

File client.cpp
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
 #include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
 #include <cstddef>
 #include <string>

 namespace io     = boost::asio;
 using tcp        = io::ip::tcp;
 using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
 using namespace std::placeholders;

 class client : public std::enable_shared_from_this<client> {

   public:
     client(io::io_context& io_context) : socket_(io_context) {}

     void start(tcp::endpoint ep);

   private:
     void on_connect(error_code const& err);

     void on_read(error_code const& err, size_t bytes_transmitted);
     void do_read();

     void on_write(error_code const& err);
     void do_write();

   private:
     tcp::socket   socket_;
     io::streambuf streambuf_;
     std::string   request_;
     std::string   response_;
 };

 #include <iostream>

 void client::start(tcp::endpoint ep) {
     socket_.async_connect(ep, [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code err) { on_connect(err); });
 }

 void client::on_connect(error_code const& err) {
     std::cerr << "on_connect: " << err.message() << std::endl;
     if (!err) {
         do_write();
     } else {
         socket_.close();
     }
 }

 void client::on_read(error_code const& err, size_t /*bytes_transmitted*/) {
     std::cerr << "on_read: " << err.message() << std::endl;
     if (!err) {
         std::cout << &streambuf_ << std::endl;
         response_.clear();

         do_write();
     } else {
         socket_.close();
     }
 }

 void client::do_read() {
     auto self = shared_from_this();
     io::async_read_until(socket_, streambuf_, "\n", [self](error_code err, size_t bytes_transmitted) {
         self->on_read(err, bytes_transmitted);
     });
 }

 void client::on_write(error_code const& err) {
     std::cerr << "on_write: " << err.message() << std::endl;
     if (!err) {
         do_read();
     } else {
         socket_.close();
     }
 }

 void client::do_write() {
     std::getline(std::cin, request_);
     std::cout << "Sending " << quoted(request_) << std::endl;
     request_ += "\n";
     io::async_write(
         socket_, io::buffer(request_),
         [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code err, size_t /*bytes_transmitted*/) { on_write(err); });
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     if (argc != 3) {
         std::cout << "usage: client <ip> <port>" << std::endl;
         return 1;
     }

     io::io_context io_context;

     auto c = std::make_shared<client>(io_context);
     c->start(tcp::endpoint({}, std::stoi(argv[2])));

     io_context.run();
 }


File server.cpp
 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
 #include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <memory>
 #include <regex>
 #include <string>
 #include <unordered_map>
 #include <utility>

 namespace io     = boost::asio;
 using tcp        = io::ip::tcp;
 using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
 using namespace std::placeholders;

 class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {

   public:
     session(tcp::socket socket, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>& storage)
         : socket_(std::move(socket))
         , storage_{storage} {}

     void start();

   private:
     void do_read();
     void on_read(error_code err, size_t bytes_transmitted);

     void do_write();
     void on_write(error_code err, size_t bytes_transmitted);

     void message_handler(std::string const& message);
     void on_put(std::string const& message);
     void on_get(std::string const& message);
     void on_del(std::string const& message);
     void on_count(std::string const& message);
     void on_dump(std::string const& message);
     bool is_valid_key(std::string const& key);
     bool is_valid_txt(std::string const& fname);

     std::string get_from_storage(std::string const& key);
     void        put_from_storage(std::string const& key, std::string const& value);

     tcp::socket   socket_;
     io::streambuf streambuf_;
     std::string   buffer_;
     std::string   response_;

     std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>& storage_;
     static std::regex const                       key_regex_;
     static std::regex const                       txt_regex_;
 };

 class server {

   public:
     server(io::io_context& io_context, std::uint16_t port)
         : io_context_(io_context)
         , acceptor_(io_context_, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
         async_accept();
     }

     void async_accept();

   private:
     io::io_context& io_context_;
     tcp::acceptor   acceptor_;

     std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> storage_;
 };

 #include <boost/asio.hpp>
 #include <cstddef>
 #include <functional>
 #include <memory>
 #include <regex>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>
 #include <utility>

 /* session implementation */

 std::regex const session::key_regex_("[A-Za-z0-9]+");
 std::regex const session::txt_regex_("[A-Za-z0-9]+\\.txt");

 void session::start() { do_read(); }

 void session::do_read() {
     io::async_read_until(socket_, streambuf_, "\n", std::bind(&session::on_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
 }

 void session::on_read(error_code err, size_t /*bytes_transmitted*/) {
     std::cerr << "on_write: " << err.message() << std::endl;
     if (!err) {
         std::string message;
         if (getline(std::istream(&streambuf_), message)) {
             message_handler(message);
             do_write();
             buffer_.clear();
         }
     } else {
         socket_.close();
     }
 }

 void session::do_write() {
     std::cerr << "Writing response: " << quoted(response_) << std::endl;
     io::async_write(socket_, io::buffer(response_),
                     std::bind(&session::on_write, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
 }

 void session::on_write(error_code err, size_t /*bytes_transmitted*/) {
     std::cerr << "on_write: " << err.message() << std::endl;
     if (!err) {
         response_.clear();
         do_read();
     } else {
         socket_.close();
     }
 }

 void session::message_handler(std::string const& message) {
     std::cerr << "message_handler: " << quoted(message) << std::endl;
     if (message.starts_with("PUT ")) {
         on_put(message);
     } else if (message.starts_with("GET ")) {
         on_get(message);
     } else if (message.starts_with("DEL ")) {
         on_del(message);
     } else if (message.starts_with("COUNT ")) {
         on_count(message);
     } else if (message.starts_with("DUMP ")) {
         on_dump(message);
     } else {
         response_ = "NE";
     }
 }

 void session::on_put(std::string const& message) {
     std::istringstream ss(message);
     std::string        tmp;
     std::string        key;
     int                cnt{};

     ss >> tmp;
     while (ss >> tmp) {
         if (++cnt == 3) {
             response_ = "NE\n";
             return;
         }
         if (cnt == 1) {
             if (!is_valid_key(tmp)) {
                 response_ = "NE\n";
                 return;
             }
             key = tmp;
         }
     }

     if (cnt != 2) {
         response_ = "NE\n";
         return;
     }

     if (std::string value = get_from_storage(key); value != "") {
         response_ = "OK " + value + "\n";
     } else {
         response_ = "OK\n";
     }
     storage_[key] = tmp;
 }

 void session::on_get(std::string const& message) {
     std::istringstream ss(message);
     std::string        tmp;
     std::string        value;
     int                cnt{};

     ss >> tmp;
     while (ss >> tmp) {
         if (++cnt == 2) {
             response_ = "NE\n";
             return;
         }
         if (!is_valid_key(tmp)) {
             response_ = "NE\n";
             return;
         }
         value = get_from_storage(tmp);
     }

     if (cnt != 1 || value == "") {
         response_ = "NE\n";
         return;
     }

     response_ = "OK " + value + "\n";
 }

 void session::on_del(std::string const& message) {
     std::istringstream ss(message);
     std::string        tmp;
     std::string        value;
     int                cnt{};

     ss >> tmp;
     while (ss >> tmp) {
         if (++cnt == 2) {
             response_ = "NE\n";
             return;
         }
         if (!is_valid_key(tmp)) {
             response_ = "NE\n";
             return;
         }
         value = get_from_storage(tmp);
     }

     if (cnt != 1 || value == "") {
         response_ = "NE\n";
         return;
     }

     storage_.erase(tmp);
     response_ = "OK " + value + "\n";
 }

 void session::on_count(std::string const& message) {
     std::istringstream ss(message);
     std::string        tmp;

     ss >> tmp;
     while (ss >> tmp) {
         response_ = "NE\n";
         return;
     }

     size_t cnt{storage_.size()};
     response_ = "OK " + std::to_string(cnt) + "\n";
 }

 void session::on_dump(std::string const& message) {
     std::istringstream ss(message);
     std::string        tmp;
     int                cnt{};

     ss >> tmp;
     while (ss >> tmp) {
         if (++cnt == 2) {
             response_ = "NE\n";
             return;
         }
     }

     if (cnt != 1 || !is_valid_txt(tmp)) {
         response_ = "NE\n";
         return;
     }

     // dumping
     response_ = "OK\n";
 }

 bool session::is_valid_key(std::string const& key) { return std::regex_match(key, key_regex_); }

 bool session::is_valid_txt(std::string const& fname) { return std::regex_match(fname, txt_regex_); }

 std::string session::get_from_storage(std::string const& key) {
     if (auto it = storage_.find(key); it != storage_.end()) {
         return it->second;
     }
     return "";
 }

 void session::put_from_storage(std::string const& key, std::string const& value) { storage_[key] = value; }

 /* server implemetation */

 void server::async_accept() {
     acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code err, tcp::socket socket) {
         if (!err) {
             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket), storage_)->start();
         }
     });
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
     if (argc < 3 || argc > 4) {
         std::cout << "usage: server <port> <limit_connections> [<dump_file>]" << std::endl;
         return 1;
     }

     io::io_context io_context;
     server         srv(io_context, static_cast<uint16_t>(std::stoi(argv[1])));
     srv.async_accept();
     io_context.run();
 }



And proof of the pudding:


I have another question, why does the server stop after closing two connections? It is after stopping and exactly two connections

Oh, yeah. I missed that. It's because you call async_accept two times (once in main, once in the constructor). Better to make it a loop: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/412a7ddad1ecf671 (note also the good habit to only call async initiation functions async_XXX)

Oh, thanks, I missed that obvious point too.
